# How can i find my wordpress database username and password?

Tags: database, wordpress, forgot-password, password-recovery

How can i find my wordpress database username and password?

By Mistake, i have deleted wp-config.php file and now i have uploaded new files.

I am Using Godaddy's windows server...

I am getting below error:

This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at 50.62.209.149:3306. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?
If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Support Forums.

Please help me as I have wasted by complete week...

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I have used godaddy before and as far as i can remember they use cPanel, if you login to cPanel, you will see a tab or a section called `Databases`, you need to go there and you should see a list of databases that you have on your server as well as users. If you remember the database name you can see which user is added to it, and reset his password, then put both username and password in the wp-config.php file and you should be good to go. If you don't see the user but see the database you can easily create a new user and add him to the database then put username and password in the wp-config.php file and that should be it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help…

Godaddy didn’t help me..

I have resolved the issue by restoreing the backup taken from UpdraftPlus – Backup/Restore plugin…

Now its working..